# How to configure SSLSocket Factory per route using Apache HTTP Components

Tags: java, ssl, client-server, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

Is there any way to setup a separate SSL Context Factory for each route in Apache HTTP Client. From the documentation i can only see we can configure SSLContextFactory per scheme not per route.

```
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> r = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", plainsf)
            .register("https", sslsf)
            .build();

    HttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(r);
    HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .build();
```

All my target endpoints are protected with HTTPS and mandates client certificate authentication. For each of these endpoint i have to select a specific client certificate & present it to the endpoint server. Currently i am seeing the only way is to create a separate HTTPClient instance for each target endpoint route & configure with SSLContext Factory instance.

I am here looking for any pointers to improving this design.

Thanks.

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have posted this question in Apache HTTP Client Forums & got the solution on how to handle this.

> One can use 'http.socket-factory-registry' context attribute to that
>   end but please note this feature is considered undocumented.
>
> http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/impl/conn/DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.html#66
>
> Please also note that one can build a custom ConnectionSocketFactory
>   that makes use of custom context attributes when creating SSL sockets.
>   That would be the recommended way to solve the issue.